# in Excel 2016, how do you select or filter rows containing various different words?

Tags: database, excel, spreadsheet

Please see picture. The sheet on the left is in stock items and the sheet on the right is all products including dims, weights, etc. I want only in stock items on the sheet on the right(with all the info).

Pretty new to excel.. Thanks in advance!

[excel sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ti35.jpg)

Comment: If I understand your question, have a look at `Vlookup`. You can use it to lookup the value on the sheet on the right and then get the corresponding range

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a `COUNTIF` on the sheet on the right. Essentially the count will tell you how many times the item appears on the sheet to the left.

In a new column type `=countif(` - don't exit yet! Excel will show a tooltip asking for 2 parameters. The first, range, is where you want to search. The easiest way to select this is to navigate over to your first spreadsheet and select the entire column A. Type a comma to move to the next parameter needed.

You should have noticed that the `countif` formula has automatically updated to include the range you just selected. For the next parameter, criteria, select the cell you want to count. In your case this will be A2 (and I'm presuming here that you will enter the formula into row 2).

Hit enter and you should be presented with a count of how many times that partNumber appears on the spreadsheet to the left. You can now copy and paste it down so each row has a count (the formula will automatically update itself as it's copied down so it's always pointing to the relevant row partNumber).

You can now filter the spreadsheet on the left for all instances where the count column is greater than 0.

Reading that back it's maybe not the clearest explanation, so I've [found a guide](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/count-sum-functions.html) on how to carry out a `COUNTIF` which you can check out.